# Type VARCHAR(n) is not supported in Kudu error when creating table in Impala 3.4.0

Tags: impala, apache-kudu

I'm trying to create a table with a varchar(30) column in Impala 3.4.0/Kudu 1.14.0
According to [this Jira ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IMPALA-5092) it is exactly Impala 3.4.0 where support for varchar columns was included for the first time.
Is there any problem with my understanding of this ticket, the syntax I use or something else that I need to fix to make this work? Did I forgot something when building or configuring Impala?

```
[Alan.local:21000] krzysztof> create table kudu_test1 (x int primary key, y varchar(40)) stored as kudu;
Query: create table kudu_test1 (x int primary key, y varchar(40)) stored as kudu
ERROR: AnalysisException: Cannot create table 'kudu_test1': Type VARCHAR(40) is not supported in Kudu

[Alan.local:21000] krzysztof> select version();
Query: select version()
Query submitted at: 2021-08-06 00:07:42 (Coordinator: http://Alan.local:25000)
Query progress can be monitored at: http://Alan.local:25000/query_plan?query_id=7a475acf748285f0:18334d4200000000
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| version()                                                                              |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| impalad version 3.4.0-RELEASE RELEASE (build 9f1c31c597b73662b76eb09a102bdeead58a96ed) |
| Built on Thu 27 May 2021 08:21:22 PM IST                                               |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: What CDH version do you have?

Comment: It's a learning exercise, so I got Hadoop 3.3.0 and Hive 3.1.2 as binaries from their respective websites. On top of that I downloaded sources for Kudu 1.14.0 and 3.4.0 as available from their Apache websites. I haven't checked git commit hashes, but I think that the addition of support for Impala 3.4.0 was done after the code was published as a tar.gz with source on the website.